# Disease probability with Bayes' Rule and airplane seats probability

Tags: statistics

I have two questions about statistical problems, I have an exam tomorrow so I would really appreciate some help.

1. There is a $6.5\%$ probability you have a disease $D$. If your father $F$ had the disease, the probability becomes $13\%$. What is the probability of being sick if your father never had the disease?
   So what I have is
   $$
   P(D) = 0.065\implies
   P(D|F) = 0.13\text{ and }P(D^{(c)}|F) = 0.87
   $$
   What I need to find is 
   $$
   P(D|F^(c)) =\frac{ P(F^{(c)}|D)P(D)}{P(F^{(c)}|D)P(D) + P(F^{(c)}|D^{(c)})P(D^{(c)})}. 
   $$
   But how do I possibly find $P(F^{(c)}|D)$?
2. A flight company has $8$ seats on its flight, but statistics say $1/10$ people who bought a ticket don't show up. So the company decides to sell $10$ tickets. What is the probability of more than $8$ people showing up?
   The probability of selling $k$ tickets is:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   &P(k=6) = 0.3\\
   &P(k=7) = 0.3\\
   &P(k=8) = 0.2\\
   &P(k=9) = 0.15\\
   &P(k=10) = 0.05
   \end{split}
   $$
   So I have to find $P(X>8|k>8)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Answer on 1):

$P(D)=P(D\mid F)P(F)+P(D\mid F^{\complement})P(F^{\complement})=P(D\mid F)P(F)+P(D\mid F^{\complement})(1-P(F)$

Now substituting $P(D)=0.065=P(F)$ and $P(D\mid F)=0.13$ you can find $P(D\mid F^{\complement})$.