# Airplane seats probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A company has small airplanes that fit $8$ people. Results show that 1 out of $10$ passengers does not show up when buying a ticket. Thus the company sells tickets to the first $10$ people who buy. The probability of k tickets sold is:
\begin{align*}
P(k=6) & = 0.3\\
P(k=7) & = 0.3\\
P(k=8) & = 0.2\\
P(k=9) & = 0.15\\
P(k=10) & = 0.05
\end{align*}
What is the probability of more people showing up than there are available places?

Attempt:
$X =$ people who show up

I'm looking for $P(X \geq 9)$.

So I believe that becomes 
$$P(X = 9|k=9)P(k=9) + P(X = 9|k=10)P(k=10) + P(X=10|k=10)P(k=10)$$

But I only know the $P(k=...)$, right? How can I find the other terms? How do I take the $1$ out of $10$ into account for 9 people? Please help me out here, this exercise really troubles me.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Previously asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089533/disease-probability-with-bayes-rule-and-airplane-seats-probability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disease probability with Bayes' Rule and airplane seats probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089533/disease-probability-with-bayes-rule-and-airplane-seats-probability)

Answer (score 3):

You've done a great job so far.  $P(X,k)$, the probability of $X$ people showing up when $k$ people have bought a ticket, is just a binomial distribution with $p=0.9$ with $k$ trials and $X$ successes.  Therefore, $$P(X,k)=\binom{k}{X}(0.9)^X(0.1)^{k-X}$$

Comment: ... where the assumption of binomial distribution (i.e, independence of individual no-shows) is a bold one in the given situation.

Comment: That's a good point.  Still, I can't imagine how one would solve this problem without making that assumption.